# Disabling startup items that run despite being unchecked on the "login items" list

Tags: macos, snow-leopard, startup

I have a number of (background) programs that startup automatically on login even though they have been disabled (unchecked) on the `Login Items` pane of the `Users & Groups` System Preferences. Examples include DropBox, ChronoSync Backgrounder, and Boingo.

**Q:** How can I disable/control these login items that don't respond to the systems preferences settings?
Related sub-questions:

- Why do the checkboxes in the login items list not work?
- What are all of the places that non-system startup items can be found/controlled?

Current system configuration: MacBook (13in Aluminum, Late 2008), Mac OS X Lion 10.7.3 (11D50), But this problem existed on Snow Leopard before upgrading to Lion.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The checkboxes are not for disabling the application launch, but if checked, the application gets hidden as if you were pressing <kbd>CMD</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>. To disable it, select it in the list and click on the Minus-button beneath that list. By that you remove them. You can't just disable them with OS X tools.

To see a summary of all LaunchAgents and LaunchDaemons you can use a software like [Lingon](http://www.peterborgapps.com/lingon/) or you can have a look at `/Library/LaunchDaemons`, `/Library/LaunchAgents`, `/System/Library/LaunchAgents`, and `/System/Library/LaunchDaemons` as well as `~/Library/LaunchDaemons`, `~/Library/LaunchAgents`, `~/Library/StartupItems`, and `/Library/StartupItems`.

Comment: Don't forget that items to run on startup can also live in `~/Library/Startup Items` and `/Library/Startup Items`.

Comment: Oh yes, silly me. There is a little label that says Hide above the column. I've now cleaned up my startup items. Thanks.

Comment: @binarybob Thanks for the tip on other places to look. I did find a few other unwanted items in `/Library/Startup Items`

Comment: And yet... com.getdropbox.dropbox.plist doesn't live in *any* of these directories.  Where is it??!

Comment: Worth noting - if you have items in LaunchAgents or LaunchDaemons folders, these commands operate on those files:

Stop this service once (will come back next log-on )

`launchctl unload /path/to/LaunchAgents/file.plist`

Stop this service and disable it

`launchctl unload -w /path/to/LaunchAgents/file.plist`

Start this service once

`launchctl load /path/to/LaunchAgents/file.plist`

Start this service and enable it:

`launchctl load -w /path/to/LaunchAgents/file.plist`

Comment: The configuration location for launchd is `/private/var/db/launchd.db/`
To list all entries in the various .plist files that create hidden overrides: `sudo find /private/var/db/launchd.db/ -type f -size +0 -iname "*.plist" -exec sudo plutil -p {} \;`

Answer (score 3):

All login items are can be found under **System Preferences → Users & Groups → User → Login Items** which you have correctly noticed.

- If you want to **disable** a startup item you have to **remove** it.
- The checkboxes are merely for **hiding**.
- *Note:*
  Some applications need their auto-login option to be disabled in their applications' preferences.

[image]

Comment: Where are the plist files for these items? I want to edit, not remove, but the plist I am looking for is not in any of the standard directories.

Comment: *Some* login items are here. There are others in other places.

Answer (score 0):

To remove BT cloud from login items search: for file 'com.f-secure.sync.BTCloud.plist' from one of the startup directories and delete file.

Comment: What is BTCloud?

Answer (score -1):

use

- `launchctl list` to check the configured start up items.
- `launchctl print-cache` to see current running config which help to locate started process.

Comment: A bit more details might be helpful here: How do these commands help to solve the problem stated in the question (what does the OP need to look for in the output)?

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different.  It's helpful when you provide an explanation on how/why you think your answer is correct.  Take a moment to review the [Tour](http://apple.stackexchange.com/tour) for more info.