# What is this menu bar icon with three right chevrons?

Tags: macos, applications, launchd, menu-bar

Recently a piece of software started showing up in my menubar.  I don't remember installing it, I have no idea what it is. The icon is three chevrons and the menu contains three items named: "Software Portal", "Vulnerability Scan" and "Inventory Scan".

[image: Icon of three right chevrons.]

Any ideas what the `>>>` menubar icon is for?

Comment: Can we assume you don't have any work profiles, work controls on your Mac or potential for an employer or co-worker to install virus scanners, malware detection or other device management software on your Mac? Also, what happens when you select Software Portal? It seems logical to conclude the software responsible will reveal itself in short order.

Comment: nothing seems to happen when i select any of the three menu options.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm fairly sure that's an agent for [LANDesk](http://community.landesk.com/support/community/systems/mac?view=all).

From [this support page](http://community.landesk.com/support/message/76144#76144):

> This starts at startup with the little three-chevron logo in the menu bar

Answer (score 4):

If it is opened on login, check login items, `{~,}/Library/Launch{Daemons,Agents}/`, or [/var/db/launchd.db/com.apple.launchd.peruser.501/overrides.plist](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/86217/disabling-startup-items-that-run-on-their-own/86280#86280).

You could also try running `sudo opensnoop` and clicking one of the menu items.

Or search for the names of the menu items:

```
grep -r 'Inventory Scan' -onlyin /Applications/
mdfind '"Inventory Scan"' -onlyin /Applications/
```