# What is this globe icon with blue down arrow in my menu bar?

Tags: macos, launchd, menu-bar

At far left of my top bar you can see a globe-like network sort of icon with what I interpret as a blue download arrow.

This icon appeared recently for the first time for unknown reasons. Clicking it, right-clicking it, double-clicking it, etc all produce no effect. It's not interactable.

What is this and how can I learn more about it and/or remove it if appropriate?

[image]

Comment: If no one guesses it, would you be willing to search for startup items or run some commands? https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/90417/5472

Comment: The issue is I don't know the name of it, so it's pretty tough to search for. In the answer you've linked he's searching for `Inventory Scan`, but I haven't got a clue like that to look for.

Comment: Yes. I’ll take a crack at updating the linked answer for you. It’s quite technical, and presumes you know convention and a bunch of obscure tools and may not even run correctly on 10.15. A non-free tool to handle this graphically would be BarTended 3 - https://www.macbartender.com/Bartender3.html (free trial, though)

Comment: Try [Accessibility Inspector](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/143637/37797), part of Apple's developer tools

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I clicked on the icon with Accessibility Inspector and a Libreoffice download window popped up. It might be related to that, if you have Libreoffice installed.

Comment: I just checked, the icon is indeed displayed while LibreOffice is running and disappears as soon as LibreOffice is terminated. Not sure how to use it though, it doesn't seem to react to any clicks.

Comment: @nohillside: For me, in LibreOffice, it shows that an update is available. So I am guessing that that is what the icon means.

Answer (score 2):

This is nothing but a notification from LibreOffice for a New update. You can update it or ignore it.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different. Great to have a new contributor. Please note that these forums work well when questions and answers are focused on a particular problem and its solution. This answer (1) proposes a solution to a problem that is different of the one asked, and (2) makes general recommendations about versions when the OP’s version is provided in the question. You might like to take the tour.

Comment: How is this different from the existing answer?

Comment: @Thinkr I don't understand either of the points in your comment. This exactly answers the question. It's not making "general recommendations about versions", it's saying that the icon is a notification that an update to LibreOffice is available. This is more information than is contained in the other answer.

Comment: @Allan if you look at the responses that have already been given, you'll see that none of them are certain about their responses, as they said "might be" or "if you installed," etc. And I respond accurately, despite being nearly 2.5 years late.

Comment: The green check mark indicates that the answer was **accepted** and thus it is assumed to be  correct.  Changing/deleting the adverb phrase from “might be” doesn’t negate that it’s basically the same answer.