# What app owns a menu bar item without installing XCode?

Tags: macos, big-sur, menu-bar

[How to identify a strange item on my menubar?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/410500/150109) says that XCode > Open Developer Tool > Accessibility Inspector can be used to find out what app/program has created a menu bar item.

How can I find out without installing XCode?

[image]

Comment: Have you checked app running using activity monitor ?

Comment: My first thought is that the list of menulets will be in a user plist somewhere. There is `com.apple.systemuiserver.plist`, but that doesn't contain third-party menulets. However, plists for individual menulets always have a key for "NSStatusItem Preferred Position", so try searching the preference folder for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In **Script Editor**, try the following *command* to see if it help gives any information to figure it out. BTW you can replace `{name, title}` with `properties` to get even more information:

```applescript
tell application "System Events" to return {name, title} of menu bar items of menu bar 1 of process "ControlCenter"
```

If it does not belong to process "ControlCenter", or it was not determined what it was, then try the following:

- Open **Automator** and create a new *workflow*.
- Click the **Record** *button* (red dot).
- Click the target **menu item** on the **menu bar**.
- Stop the recording.
- In the **Watch Me Do** *action* created by the recording, drag and drop the *event* to the open area just below the **Watch Me Do** *action*.

It should create a **Run AppleScript** *action* in which it should show the name of the `application process` to which it belongs.

As an example I clicked the icon for **Hammerspoon** and in the **Run AppleScript** *action* there was a line e.g.:

```
set uiScript to "click menu bar item 1 of menu bar 2 of application process \"Hammerspoon\"
```