# Removing an icon from Mac OS X menubar when Cmd+Drag won't work

Tags: macos, mac

I noticed this message icon show up on my menubar and I can't tell which app it belongs to. I've tried to click on the "settings" gear but it doesn't take me to anything.

The icon is a square chat icon - I would upload it but I don't have enough reputation points on this site yet to do so.

I'd like to:

1. Figure out which app this icon belongs to
2. Disallow the service/app from running on my system
3. Remove it from my menubar.

How can I do this?

Comment: The CMD+drag shortcut only works for Apple system apps. The app Bartender (http://www.macbartender.com), which has a free trial, can help you find the apps with a menu bar item. You could install that, find out which app it is, get rid of it and then uninstall Bartender.

Comment: Magic. Installed this app and the only thing it could remotely be close to is the new Google Chrome Canary's "Message Center" notification feature. However, I can't seem to remove the damn thing without removing Canary, which just maybe the reason to stop using it.

Comment: As it turns out, when you quit Canary, the icon goes away. Would have been helpful if the app's icon matched the menu bar icon. Thanks for the Bartender app suggestion - very helpful.

Answer (score 2):

If it is opened at login, check login items in the Users & Groups preference pane, `{~,}/Library/Launch{Daemons,Agents}/`, or [/var/db/launchd.db/com.apple.launchd.peruser.501/overrides.plist](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/86217/disabling-startup-items-that-run-on-their-own/86280#86280).

You could also try opening Activity Monitor and quitting all processes that seem suspicious.

Comment: There are a number of com.apple.launchd.peruser items listed - is 501 always the current logged in user?

Comment: No, but 501 is usually the first normal user account created on the computer.

Answer (score 2):

Bartender was mentioned already, but if you like free, try [Broomstick](http://www.zibity.com/broomstick).

[image]

> Broomstick is the easiest way to hide menubar icons that you don’t like. While most apps that create a menubar icon allow you to hide it, some apps don’t provide this option. Broomstick lets you take back control of your menubar!

Answer (score 2):

No one has answered the question yet.

Open the Messages app and go to Preferences. Under the General tab you'll see check boxes for Account Status (towards the middle of the window). Uncheck, Show Status in Menu Bar