# Where that icon on my OS X menu bar comes from?

Tags: menu-bar

Anyone could tell me which application stands behind this icon on the menu bar?

[image: Unknown icon]

I tried to figure it out but I couldn’t. Nothing happens when I click on it.

Comment: @MK The linked question is about removing icons from the bar, not about identifying the one shown in the question.

Comment: Yes, that's true. I thought the pointers in that questions may help. I'll unflag and just link it here.

Comment: See http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/93461/removing-an-icon-from-mac-os-x-menubar-when-cmddrag-wont-work for some ideas on how to identify the app.

Answer (score 4):

I don't recognize the icon, but I may have a way to find out which app it belongs to.

[Bartender](http://www.macbartender.com) is an app that organises the menu bar apps, but can also show which apps are already there.
It's a paid app, but you can install the trial, find the mystery app, then uninstall Bartender.

A screenshot from an installation of mine.
[image: List of menu bar items]

Tip: If you just want to remove the icon you may be able to ⌘-drag it away from the menubar, but for that to work the app needs to be an Apple built-in app or use the same menu bar hooks.

Comment: Unfortunately ⌘-drag is not working on it.

As to the Bartender, I just installed it but even there I couldn’t find a clue what might be the holder of the icon. I tried to hide every single icon, and made all of them hidden, but that one stayed.

Comment: @MartinMetodiev That's so weird. Maybe try going through your Applications folder (sorted by date modified, probably) to see if you can find it.